# apache setup shows directory files instead of the website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I just finished setting up a local site for development with apache2 on OSX, but what happens is that when i go to my site (cakephp with htaccess and index.php) i get simply a list of the files and folders that i can click, instead of the actual website.

I tried to put an `index.html` and the index page loads right. But when i remove it, i get a list of files in the directory.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the line:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add type for php files in httpd.conf file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Remember to restart apache after this. Can you post your .htaccess file?

Additionally, you could simply download and install MAMP on your Mac. It's a pack with Apache+PHP+MySql. You can find it here: http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html but remember to uninstall apache that you already installed (to avoid conflicts).

Comment: yeah, you are right. i think its a php problem, but i dont have time to investigate it, i will go with mamp for now. thanx!

Comment: If you configured Apache only, you probably have to install PHP and add it to Apache. But from my experience, MAMP is sufficient for most uses and there is no need to do this manually ;)